# How to create a button in html and change into a blue button

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to crate a button in HTML.
Should it be type: sumbit or button? What is the difference?

And how is it possible to change the button into a blue button maybe
I know with CSS but I can use the id for the or the class what is the difference.

Comment: This site is not for this kind of questions.http://www.w3schools.com/html/ and http://www.w3schools.com/css/
Good luck.

Comment: I use it but i wanted to try it with examples... :(

Comment: This extremely basic question **should really not receive any answers**.

Comment: @WegUndweg How much time did you spend researching this before posting, honeslty now? The question is basic HTML/CSS. However, the question to me seems to go deeper than what you posted. Are you wanting to use this with a form and possibly PHP and a database/email?

Comment: the difference between a button and an input/submit can vary and is rather broad as to what those differences are. Some have "submit" types, when others have "button" types. Some only work in JS, while others in PHP, or a mix of both, with ajax.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example:

```css
button {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button>This is my button</button>
```

In CSS you can use any of the name of the element, it's id or it's class to target an element (or any of them combined).

Comment: The question seems to go deeper than what was posted. Read it over again and see some of the comments I left under their question.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I agree with that :)

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are generally used with Javascript. And, submit buttons are used with [forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp). You can find more on forms here. There are `a` [anchor](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_anchor.asp) tags also, which is how you can link to pages or places on a page.

In are right [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp) is the main way people change the colour of things in Web design.

I would recommend you don't use ID for css and stick to classes. More on ids and classes [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/).

You can change the colour with a mouse hover event. Using the developer tools in chrome is a great play to discover what can be done. And a site like www.w3schools.com is a good start for beginners. Here is a starter on how to change colour with a hover event

```
.my-button {
    color: black;
}

.my - button {
    color: red;
 }
```

Hope this helps.
Good luck and happy learning!

[1](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp):

Comment: `.my - button` will select `button` elements which are descendants of `-` elements which are descendants of element with the CSS class `my`.